# Rsquared estimation

Tags: python, numpy

What is the error in this function for R-squared estimation?

```
def R2(X, Y, model):
    Y_mean = np.mean(Y, axis=0)
    pred = model.predict(X)
    res = np.sum(np.square(Y - pred))
    tot = np.sum(np.square(Y - Y_mean))
    r2 = 1 - res / tot

    return r2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that your function to compute the coefficient of determination R2 is correct. You can test this by computing R2 for Y against Y which gives 1.0 as expected.

The problem is that the shape of Y and pred are not the same.
If you reshape pred to match Y's shape, the math behave as expected.

```
def R2(X, Y, model):
    Y_mean = np.mean(Y, axis=0)
    pred = model.predict(X)
    print Y.shape, pred.shape
    pred = pred.reshape(Y.shape[0])
    print Y.shape, pred.shape
    res = np.sum(np.square(Y - pred))
    tot = np.sum(np.square(Y - Y_mean))
    r2 = 1 - res / tot

    return r2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My bad. I modified the questions and tags so that it can be found and used by people having the same problem